# Почему не работает условие на input?

Tags: python, input

На языке Python я столкнулся с проблемой условий. Что я делаю не так? Почему если прописать в input(переменная reason) w в нижнем или верхнем регистре то ничего не выведется.

```
if reason == ["w", "W"]:
    print("true")
```

Comment: `if reason.lower() == 'w'` или `if reason in ['w', 'W'] `

Comment: Ко всему прочему, надеюсь, что у Вас записано как `reason = input() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно сработать

```py
if reason in ["w", "W"]:
    print("true")
```

Вы пытаетесь сравнить строку и лист. Это не верно. Вам нужно спросить "есть ли строка(символ) в данном списке"

Чтобы избежать сравнивание строчной и прописной буквы, то можно сделать так:

```py
if reason.lower() == "w":
    print("true")
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что ни `w`, ни `W` никогда не будут равны списку.